# Failed to load resource: fontawesome-webfont.woff2 Laravel 5.5

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, laravel-5.5, woff, woff2

I am writing a web application and trying to use `font-awesome` icons.
The fonts are imported to the right directories but when I load the page the icons appear as blank squares. (Example in attached picture).

[image]

When I press <kbd>F12</kbd> this is the error I get: (Also in attached picture)

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   fontawesome-webfont.woff2  a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   fontawesome-webfont.woff a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   fontawesome-webfont.ttf a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image]

Those files do exist and I can see them.
I managed to find some solutions by changing the `web.config` file but this is not helping with `laravel`. 
I can't find any appropriate solution for `laravel 5.5` online. Would appreciate help!

PS - I don't know yet if this is relevant, but I use the icons in `vue.js` components.

Comment: Have you run `npm install` and `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yes i have run `npm install` and`npm run dev`, i have also run `npm run watch`. The more I look it appears to be related to those file extensions and mime-types, but nothing i tried works.

Answer (score 0):

IIS will not serve files of unknown type.

1. In IIS, go to MIME Types.
2. Right click in a blank area and select Add.
3. File name extension: .woff2
4. MIME type: font/x-woff
5. Click OK

[image]